# (Java) Is it possible to generate 2 different graphics window? If so, how to do it with this code?

Tags: java

The code below is programmed to produce a coloured image in a 200x200 display. However, I am wondering, lets say I want to generate another window but this window will be a 200x200 sketch which is mostly white but the colour boundaries of the original picture are in black, how do I achieve this?

In short, the first window is coloured. The second window is a black and white sketch of the first window. Both windows are to appear next to each other. Do you know how to generate such results? If so, could you please help me?

```
//Setting the size of the graphics window
    final int WINDOW_DIMENSION = 200;
    EasyGraphics generate = new EasyGraphics(WINDOW_DIMENSION,WINDOW_DIMENSION);

    //Constructing the arrays
    char[][] firstArray = new char[WINDOW_DIMENSION][WINDOW_DIMENSION];
    char[] secondArray = scan.toCharArray();

    //Using "for" loop to generate 2D array
    int line = WINDOW_DIMENSION;
    int column = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < WINDOW_DIMENSION*WINDOW_DIMENSION; i++) {
        column++;
        if (i%WINDOW_DIMENSION == 0) {
            line--;
            column = 0;
        }

        firstArray[column][line]=secondArray[i];
    }

    //Plotting the colours for respective range of numbers
    for (int a = 0; a < WINDOW_DIMENSION; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < WINDOW_DIMENSION; b++) {
            if (firstArray[a][b]=='0' || firstArray[a][b]=='1' || firstArray[a][b]=='2' || firstArray[a][b]=='3') {
                generate.setColor(66,167,243);
                generate.plot(a,b);
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='4' || firstArray[a][b]=='5') {
                generate.setColor(0,255,77);
                generate.plot(a,b);
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='6' || firstArray[a][b]=='7') {
                generate.setColor(51,183,91);
                generate.plot(a,b);
            } 

            else if (firstArray[a][b]=='8' || firstArray[a][b]=='9') {
                generate.setColor(102,51,0);
                generate.plot(a,b);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Your help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define what is a boundary  if it's juste a change of color or nuances of the same color are counted as the same one, if you take into account nuances you should define a distance between color (for exemple RedDiff+GreenDeff+BlueDiff) and if it's less than a certain value you color the bit in black.
then you can do something like that:

```
for (int a = 1; a < WINDOW_DIMENSION; a++) {
    for (int b = 1; b < WINDOW_DIMENSION; b++) {
        generate.setColor(255,255,255);
        if(array[a,b]!=array[a-1,b] || array[a,b]!=array[a,b-1])
             generate.setColor(0,0,0);
        generate.plot(a,b);
    }
}
```

before this you juste need to construct the first line and the first column using something like the code above then use the code above for the other pixels

Comment: Do I use this code and replace all the existing pixels? @user1928596

Comment: you may want to use this code on the genertaed (colored) picture

Comment: I want to generate a picture like the [link](http://prntscr.com/57yi87), but the picture has a few missing pixels. That's why the line isn't continuous.

What I would like to do is to generate the same picture that has solid outline of the image. In other words,the colour boundaries of the original picture are in black. 

I know I have to use for loops again but I just don't know how to write it out and implement it into my existing code. @user1928596

Answer (score 0):

If by "black and white", you mean greyscale, you need to determine which gradient to use. There are three major methods. Suppose you have [R, G, B] for each coordinate in your array. I'm assuming you're using AWT Color. When that is the case, you can develop the grayscale coordinate by applying the lightness method:

```
int intensity = 
   (max((double)color.getRed(), (double)color.getGreen(), (double)color.getBlue()}) +
   min((double)color.getRed(), (double)color.getGreen(), (double)color.getBlue()})
   / 2) * 255

Color newColor = new Color(intensity, intensity, intensity)
```

Or the average method:

```
int intensity = (((double)color.getRed() + (double)color.getGreen() + 
   (double)color.getBlue())/3)*255;
```

Or the luminosity method:

```
int intensity = ((double)color.getRed() * 0.21 +
   (double)color.getGreen() * 0.72 +
   (double)color.getBlue() * 0.07) * 255;
```

or really any other as long as you have a satisfactory slide in lightness between adjacent colors.

If you really mean just black and white, then user1928596's suggestion will definitely do it; but if this is for a course, you may need to adjust the sensitivity to color differences later. Broadening that definition a bit, programs like Photoshop and Gimp generally use the error function on the difference between the two adjacent colors, and a boundary on how different they need to be to be considered an edge. The error function can be found in Apache Commons, at org.apache.commons.math3.special.Erf. I might suggest something like this:

```
 boolean edge = Math.abs(Erf.erf(Intensity2 - Intensity1)) > σ;
```

where σ is your threshold, between 0 and 1, for an edge. If true, there's an edge, if false, it's a more minor smear and can be ignored.

Comment: I want to generate a picture like the [link](http://prntscr.com/57yi87). I just want to produce an graphical window which only display the colour boundaries of the image in solid black line. That means the background would mostly be white in colour. I just don't know how to write a code that would generate such a result. @michael